# Concatenate XML variables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query in a stored procedure retrieving some data in XML format to be returned in a variable `@xml_data`, like this:

```
SELECT @xml_data = (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT   1 AS Tag
                ,0 AS Parent
                .....
        FROM    MyTable
        WHERE   id = @id

        UNION ALL

        SELECT   2 AS Tag
                ,1 AS Parent
                ....
        FROM    MyTable2
        WHERE   id = @id

        UNION ALL

        SELECT   3 AS Tag
                ,2 AS Parent
                ....
        FROM    MyTable3
        WHERE   id = @id
    ) results
FOR XML EXPLICIT, TYPE)
```

This is working like the proverbial dream :)

However, I'd like to concatenate a header to this XML (e.g. `<xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>`) and can't figure out how to do it. I've tried converting to `NVARCHAR`, selecting the two variables in one statement but can't seem to get it right.

Can anyone help??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing like this:

```
DECLARE @x xml 
DECLARE @strXML varchar(MAX)
SET @x=N'<Employee><Name>Luftwaffe</Name></Employee>'
set @strXML = '<xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>' + CONVERT(varchar(MAX),@x)
SELECT @strXML
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

You can just declare the string at the beginning and concatenate them together:

```
declare @xml_data nvarchar(MAX)

set @xml_data = '<xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>'

SELECT @xml_data = @xml_data +  (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT   1 AS Tag
                ,0 AS Parent
                .....
        FROM    MyTable
        WHERE   id = @id

        UNION ALL

        SELECT   2 AS Tag
                ,1 AS Parent
                ....
        FROM    MyTable2
        WHERE   id = @id

        UNION ALL

        SELECT   3 AS Tag
                ,2 AS Parent
                ....
        FROM    MyTable3
        WHERE   id = @id
    ) results
FOR XML EXPLICIT, TYPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way, in my opinion:

```
declare @xml1 xml
declare @xml2 xml
declare @xml3 xml
select @xml1='<name>testname</name>'
select @xml2='<value>testvalue</value>'
select @xml3 = 
(
    select @xml1 AS xml1, @xml2 AS xml2
    for xml path('')
)
select @xml3
```